# replace a drawable instead of Another drawable

Tags: android, drawable

i use of multi functional button This means that a button at In different situations, it has different reactions .examle:when text button is yes accepts.
if is no reject. i use a Drawable for Textcolor button The function of the button changes Drawable changes too.But the problem is that The output is different .The color of what should be,not be .The color is different with That color that i choiced.it seems like Two drawable are merged.please guide me

```
   if (bsc.getText().toString().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.inotpaid))) {
                tfr.setText(R.string.select_pay_way);
                tsc.setText(R.string.also);
                bfr.setText(R.string.app_intro);
                bsc.setText(R.string.site_way);
                bth.setText(R.string.bank_way);
                bth.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_style_trans));
                bth.setTextColor(R.drawable.change_text_color);
            }




<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="@color/blueyellows" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:color="#ffffff"/>
</selector>



<Button
    android:id="@+id/bth"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:text="@string/price_que"
    android:textColor="@drawable/change_text_color_black"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by `The color of what should be,not be .The color is different with That color that i choiced.it seems like Two drawable are merged.please guide me` ?

Comment: In the second drawable, the color must change to white, but the color is gray

Comment: Do you want to change color based on button click or some other logic ?

Comment: My English is not good.
I always have trouble
Sending my own requests to other people
And conversely!
But I try

Comment: Try Goole Translate

Comment: The color of the button is white.
After Pressed is blue.
In the next operation button
The color is blue.
After pressing the white one.
The problem is here.
That
When the button is clicked
The color of the base should be blue, but it is gray.
I think the use of multiple drawable has fixed this problem.

Comment: my language is Persian
Google does not have strong support
Using Google Translator makes things harder.
My problem is to convey the concept in programming.

Comment: I understand I had the same problem when I started

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a boolean value for toggling your button. Based on the value it can change the functionality. You can do something like this.

```
private boolean isButtonPressed = false;

 public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isButtonPressed) {
                isButtonPressed = false;
            } else {
                isButtonPressed = true;
            }
       }
```

Now based on the value of the isButtonPressed, you can provide different functionality for the button like :

```
if(isButtonPressed) {
     button.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
     } else {
     button.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
      }
   }
```

I hope this was helpful.